# When is the representation ring of neutral component of reductive group flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, algebraic-k-theory

Let $G$ be a reductive complex algebraic group, not necessarily connected. Let $G^\circ$ be the connected component of the identity. When is it true that $R(G^\circ)$ is flat over each connected component of $\mathrm{Spec}(R(G))$? Here $R(G)$ is the representation ring of $G$.

Comment: What does it mean for a ring to be flat over a scheme? Is there a typo in here?

Comment: $R(G^\circ)$ is an $R(G)$-module, and if it is flat as an $R(G)$-module, then $R(G^\circ)$ gives in fact a vector bundle on $\mathrm{Spec}(R(G))$. I think that what I'm trying to ask is how to see that while this doesn't exactly happen, one does obtain a vector bundle on each connected component of $\mathrm{Spec}(R(G)$. I think this is already what happens for $\mathrm{O}_2(\mathbb{C})$.